# Регистрация в 2 шага в Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

Всем привет)) Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу. У меня есть обычная форма регистрации которую сгенерировал Gii

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm'); ?>
<div class = "form">
    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class = "row">
        <?php echo $form->label($model, 'username'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'username'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class = "row">
        <?php echo $form->label($model, 'password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model, 'password'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class = "row">
        <?php echo $form->label($model, 'email'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'email') ?>
    </div>

    <div class = "submitButton">
        <?php echo CHtml::button('Продолжить', array('onClick'=>'$("#form_modal").dialog("open");')); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Чуть выше этого кода расположен виджет CJuiDialog:

```
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
    'id'=>'form_modal',
    'options'=>array(
        'autoOpen'=>false,
        'modal'=>true,
        'width'=>540,
        'height'=>328,
        'resizable'=>false,
    ),
));
echo "тут правила сайта";
echo CHtml::submitButton('Я прочитал и принимаю правила проекта');
$this->endWidget();
```

И мне надо, чтобы форма отправлялась и проходила валидацию после нажатия на эту кнопку, однако у меня это не работает, просто кнопка нажимается и ничего не происходит(даже страница не переазагружается), я пробовал поставить перед началом виджета Диалога, виджет начала формы, однако тут тоже не срабатывает, как можно решить эту проблему? Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Если вот тут `'id'=>'form_modal'` это айди самой формы, то нужно начало виджета нужно прописать так : `<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array('id' => 'form_modal')); ?>`